# How to retrieve or view build/test artifacts/results from a docker multi stage build?

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile, build-process, docker-build

Are the build artifacts or test results from a docker multi-stage build retrievable(be made available on the host machine on which the docker build container has executed).
If they are, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it depends on where you have written the build artifacts to disk inside the container. That location needs to be mounted in when running the docker command from the host machine using the [-v or --mount flag](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

Once mounted, writing to the mounted folder inside the container, makes the files available in the corresponding folder on the host machine.

Word of warning if running as root inside your container, the permissions on your generated files may be too strict for your build service to remove!
Use the --user flag to ease this.

Comment: Should the --user option be passed to docker build cli or how? Could you add bit more details on this.

Comment: Also note that, at startup time, if you use `docker run -v` to bind-mount a host directory into the container, the directory contents replace the image contents before anything else happens; you can't bind-mount an empty host directory into a container and have the contents of the image copied into the directory for you.

Comment: @samshers https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/ 

Add it as a flag to your docker run command, or in the Dockerfile as USER <user>[:<group>]